# Upgrading MythTV from 0.25 to 0.27 fails

Tags: upgrade, mythtv

I'm using ubuntu 12.10.  I installed MythTV from the software center which installed 0.25. That version is no longer supported so I opted to install 0.27 using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.27 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mythtv
```

Install result:

```
mythtv is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5
  libctemplate2 libzip2 mysql-utilities php-mythtv php5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-mysql python-mysql.connector python-pysqlite2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

My MythTV version is still 0.25.

I have tried deleting MySQL and MythTV several times and reinstalling MythTV again using the above code but cannot get 0.27 to install. Synaptic Package Manager doesn't show any upgrades for MythTV. What the heck is going on? How can I upgrade MythTV?

Answer (score -1):

I use the Mythbuntu PPA to keep mine updated.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.27
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mythtv
```

Find info on the [Mythbuntu PPA at Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~mythbuntu/+archive/0.27).

**Edit:**

If the Mythbuntu PPA is not appearing in Synaptic or Software Sources, check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. It should contain the following entries:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/0.27/ubuntu precise main  <-- Binary
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/0.27/ubuntu precise main  <--Source
```

Or add them through Software Sources by adding the PPA manually using the PPA URI's as above, one entry each for the Binary and Source, with `precise` being the Distribution and `main` being the Components field entries.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And if you want to install the MythTV server (backend):

```
sudo apt-get install mythtv-backend-master
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install mythtv-frontend
```

for the MythTV fronted client.

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem? He says he already did this.

Comment: @DavidEdwards Downvoting my answer after edits that were not visible at the time of my answer = not cool.

Comment: I checked the edit history for the question before I down voted. Even the original question specified that he was using the PPA already, and according to the timestamps the subsequent edits where made before your answer was posted.

Comment: I think that `add-apt-repository ppa:mythbuntu/0.27` will add a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. You need to check that file is present and that there are _not_ any Mythbuntu entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Adding the PPA through `add-apt-repository` does not create an entry in `sources.list.d/`, only in the `sources.list` file.

Comment: @DavidEdwards I too looked at the edit history and I will swear up and down that there is an error somewhere in the Edit routines, because the OP's reference to adding the PPA was not there when I answered. I would not have parroted a command set that the OP had already attempted.

Comment: From the man page of `add-apt-repository`: "ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> will be expanded to the full deb line of the PPA and added into a new file in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory"